# Is it possible to delay OSX's system sound?

Tags: macos, audio

Let's say for instance that you are watching a stream with sound that's two seconds too early. No matter how many times you refresh, you still hear sound 2 secs before the image appears.

Would it be possible to then programmatically delay the whole system's sound to match the image? After searching for a while I did not find anything on the topic, for free at least.

Comment: Watching a stream of what, from where, using which tools?

Comment: Just a random stream, or whatever source that has audio early compared to the video that you cannot change. It would be handy to be able to delay the system sound by `x` ms, but maybe it would cause more problems that it would solve ?

Comment: Are you talking about Safari? Or ffplay? Or QuickTime? Or VLC?

Comment: Neither, I'm talking about ```OSX's system sound```, as in the whole system sound. I don't know how to phrase it better! But then again, I'm probably missing something or I guess that would have been done already.

Comment: I believe it's not a programming-related question, so it's not the right forum. However, what I would do in this case -- I would use AudioHijack (http://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) to capture either system audio or audio from a particular app, and run it through a delay plugin, there a plenty of them, including standard Apple's AU Delay plugin.